# Changing views with swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swift, view, swipe

I have googled as much as I can to try to find this. I am new to app development and programming in general. I want to have a view return to the previous view via swipe gesture.

Here is my ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var changeView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipeDown:")
    recognizer.direction = .Down
    self.view .addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

    func swipeDown(recognizer : UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("HowToPlaySegue", sender: self)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}
```

Now with that there I am also a beginner with the new Xcode. If i remember correctly gestures used to be like buttons with a simple control-drag to the view and it would work.

In xcode I have my view that I want to swipe and I have the main view. What am I doing wrong?

error I receive now. Right now my AppDelegate.swift has not been touched. I believe that is where my selector goes, but I am unsure and I couldn't find much about this particular stuff.

> [Swipe_t.ViewController swipeDown:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe94bc7a080
>   2015-03-05 23:10:15.637 Swipe't[32779:3391684] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swipe_t.ViewController swipeDown:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: If you insert view and main view in a navigation controller swipe back gesture is include! This is can help you: [](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your `swipeDown` function is inside `viewDidLoad`. Shouldn't that be outside the viewDidLoad braces?

**EDIT(Adding Modified Code)**

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipeDown:")
    recognizer.direction = .Down
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}

func swipeDown(recognizer : UISwipeGestureRecognizer) 
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("HowToPlaySegue", sender: self)
}
```

2) Secondly, though I am not sure about your use case,from information you have provided, I think you can utilize [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/). No need to implement swiping behavior yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much! You were right I had the function inside the viewDidLoad when it shouldn't have been. Thank you very much!